# QCheckBox only executes when checked twice

Tags: python, qt-designer, qcheckbox

I have a QCheckBox (`deselect_checkbox`) which, when checked, sets another QCheckBox (`first_checkbox`) and itself to `False`. However, it only works every other time and I'm not sure why. Here is the code:

```
def deselect_func():
    if self.dockwidget.deselect_checkbox.isChecked():
        self.dockwidget.first_checkbox.setChecked(False)
        self.dockwidget.deselect_checkbox.setChecked(False)

self.dockwidget.deselect_checkbox.stateChanged.connect(deselect_func)
```

How can I get the function to run everytime I check `deselect_checkbox`?

---

Using QGIS 2.16.0 with Qt Designer 4.8.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up "check-state" and "checked".

The former can have three states: Unchecked, PartiallyChecked, and Checked, whereas the latter is just True/False. If you call `setChecked()` instead of `setCheckState()`, a state-change won't be registered. Thus, on the next click, a `stateChanged` signal won't be emitted (because no change is detected).

To fix this, your code therefore must either look like this:

```
def deselect_func():
    if self.dockwidget.deselect_checkbox.isChecked():
        self.dockwidget.first_checkbox.setChecked(False)
        self.dockwidget.deselect_checkbox.setChecked(False)

self.dockwidget.deselect_checkbox.toggled.connect(deselect_func)
```

or like this:

```
def deselect_func():
    if self.dockwidget.deselect_checkbox.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
        self.dockwidget.first_checkbox.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
        self.dockwidget.deselect_checkbox.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)

self.dockwidget.deselect_checkbox.stateChanged.connect(deselect_func)
```

But note that this means `deselect_checkbox` will never been shown as checked, since it is always immediately unchecked. Is that what you really intended?

Comment: Ahh, thank you very much, this makes a lot of sense! And yes, this is what I intended :). Also, I think you meant _"Checked, PartiallyChecked, and Unchecked"_?